# Scraped images are somehow protected against scraping

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape image URLs from a website and display the images on another site (using BeautifulSoup), but the website in question (yupoo.com) has some sort of protection against loading images from their server if you don't browse their site.

How to reproduce my problem:

You can't load this image:
 https://photo.yupoo.com/0832club_v/0058b582/96f83ddb.jpeg

Now visit this site: https://0832club.x.yupoo.com/29611853?uid=1

Now open the link above
 "https://photo.yupoo.com/0832club_v/0058b582/96f83ddb.jpeg" and for
 some reason it now works...

I checked for cookies and stuff, but I seriously don't understand how they protect their images

Comment: Normally browser may send cookies and headers (like `referer`) when it loads images and server may check it. You may have to send all there information to download it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send header `referer` and then server think that it is load from page `https://0832club.x.yupoo.com/29611853?uid=1`

```
import requests

url = 'https://photo.yupoo.com/0832club_v/0058b582/96f83ddb.jpeg'

headers = {
    'referer': 'Referer: https://0832club.x.yupoo.com/29611853?uid=1'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(r.content[:100])  # you can see string `JFIF` or `GIF` in content

f = open('output.jpg', 'wb')
f.write(r.content)
f.close()
```

With `referer` I see string `JFIF` in `content` so it sends `JPG`. Without `referer` I see string `GIF` in `content` so it sends `GIF`

---

You can also check

```
print(r.headers['Content-Type'])
```

and with `referer` it returns `image/jpeg`, without `referer` it returns `image/gif`

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. 
But my python script already scrapes the right url from the <img src="x"> tag. The problem is that users who open my site get the .gif displayed. 

What i would like to see: https://i.imgur.com/kxWsRuu.png
What everyone who wasn't on yupoo site bevore sees: https://i.imgur.com/dpLtS6i.png

Sorry for formulating my question so imprecise

Comment: Yoiu have to download image on your server. You can't uses URLs to original images on `yupoo.com` because web browser will always uses your server url as `referer` and `yupoo.com` will always block images.

Comment: BTW: linking to objects/images on other server is called [hotlinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking) and many servers block these links. Probably the only method is to download images to your server. But hotlinking or downloading both can be treated as illegal.